# Adding images and filenames to word doc. 3 columns

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I have been using the code below to insert a 2 column table into a word doc with images and names that are selected part way through the process.
I have adjusted this to produce a 3 column table but have failed to insert 3 columns of images. I have made a number of attempts and have random results.

So to clarify. I want to adjust the VB to produce a 3 column image list with the names in a word doc.

Many thanks
Peter

Clarification further to the two comments received.

The original code as pointed out was from a previous post that produced a two column table.
The image shows the 3 column table that the code below produces but it never fills in the 3rd column. I need to fill each row with images and details below.

[Shows how the original formatted table and the new 3 column table but only 2 columns filled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4xik.png)

```
Sub AddPics()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim oTbl As Table, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, StrTxt As String
    'Select and insert the Pics
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .Title = "Select image files and click OK"
        .Filters.Add "Images", "*.gif; *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.bmp; *.tif; *.png"
        .FilterIndex = 2
        If .Show = -1 Then
            'Add a 2-row by 3-column table with 5cm columns to take the images
            Set oTbl = Selection.Tables.Add(Selection.Range, 2, 3)
            With oTbl
                .AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitFixed)
                .Columns.Width = CentimetersToPoints(5)
                'Format the rows
                Call FormatRows(oTbl, 1)
            End With:
            CaptionLabels.Add Name:="Picture"
            For i = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
                j = Int((i + 1) / 2) * 2 - 1
                k = (i - 1) Mod 2 + 1
                'Add extra rows as needed
                If j > oTbl.Rows.Count Then
                    oTbl.Rows.Add
                    oTbl.Rows.Add
                    Call FormatRows(oTbl, j)
                End If
                'Insert the Picture
                ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture _
                  FileName:=.SelectedItems(i), LinkToFile:=False, _
                  SaveWithDocument:=True, Range:=oTbl.Rows(j).Cells(k).Range

                'Get the Image name for the Caption
                StrTxt = Split(.SelectedItems(i), "\")(UBound(Split(.SelectedItems(i), "\")))
                'The row below will lose the last parts of the file name if there is more then one Dot in the filename
                StrTxt = ": " & StrTxt
                'Comment above out and uncomment below if only one dot in the filename
                'StrTXT = ": " & Split(StrTxt, ".")(0)
              
                
                'Insert the Caption on the row below the picture
                With oTbl.Rows(j + 1).Cells(k).Range
                    .InsertBefore vbCr
                    .Characters.First.InsertCaption _
                      Label:="Picture", Title:=StrTxt, _
                      Position:=wdCaptionPositionBelow, ExcludeLabel:=False
                    .Characters.First = vbNullString
                    .Characters.Last.Previous = vbNullString
                End With

            Next i

        Else

        End If

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

```
Sub FormatRows(oTbl As Table, x As Long)
    With oTbl
        With .Rows(x)
        'row height for pictures 5cm
            .Height = CentimetersToPoints(5)
            .HeightRule = wdRowHeightExactly
            .Range.Style = "Normal"
        End With

        With .Rows(x + 1)
            .Height = CentimetersToPoints(0.5)
            .HeightRule = wdRowHeightExactly
            .Range.Style = "Caption"
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the exact problem with the above code? What is the input when the incorrect result is produced?

Comment: Your code is based on: https://www.msofficeforums.com/drawing-and-graphics/49547-automate-insertion-multiple-images-into-document.html. See the original code there.

Comment: I used the link provided above by macropod and this has resolved the problem. Much better solution.